# phpbb3 and cakephp 2.x integration issue

Tags: cakephp, phpbb3

I have installed phpbb3 version in my cakephp application. I want to use same login for phpbb which is used in my cake application. But I am getting issues in it.

I have used this component [PhpBB3 APi Bridge](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/wilsonsheldon/2009/01/13/phpbb3-api-bridge) but it gives error that cannot redeclare user class. I am using User class in my application and cannot modify it. It seems phpbb also use User class.

After reading on net, I am inserting direct values in phpbb_session table and saving sid cookie but it's not logging in the user to phpbb forum.

I have searched alot but could not find any workable solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution finally. Just adding it here for other people:

Set the username and password (plain text) in session.

In phpbb/index.php file, write session_start() on top and then later after some lines, add the following line:

$auth->login($_SESSION["custom_username"], $_SESSION["custom_username_password"]); //custom login

don't forget to change session variable names. It should be same which you have defined in your cake application.

Ideally, you should set this value in header file of phpbb.

Comment: Can you please more elaborate your comment as an answer. I am having same problem